# Как сделать экранную клавиатуру на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, клавиатура

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему с экранной клавиатурой.Я хочу написать,что типа экранной клавиатуры виндовс,но с другими символами.У меня возникла проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку, текс печатается моментально,а в фокусе находится окно моего приложения, поэтому вписывать текст некуда.

Вот мой код:

```
from tkinter import*
from functools import partial
import keyboard
import time
write=keyboard.write
press=keyboard.press_and_release
button='⚀⚁⚂⚃⚄⚅❶❷❸❹❺❻❼❽❾❿➀➁➂➃➄➅➆➇➈➉❌⟸➗⟳⟹⛇⛪⏳❝❞☀⛱⚒⛥⛈⛟⚙⨸✍⏰⏱☔✟⚗⚑♔❣❤♕♖♗♘♙♚♛☕☂❄➔➕➖➘➙➚➛➜➝➞➟➠➡➢➣➤➥➦➧➨➩➪➫➬➭➮➯➰➱➲➳➴➵➶➷➸➹➺➻➼➽➾♜'
button=list(button)
n=1
root=Tk()

def com(a):
    time.sleep(3)
    global write
    write(a)
def cordinat(n):
    inr=15
    str_str=((n//inr)+1)
    if    (n%inr==0):
        str_str-=1
    nomer=n%inr
    if  (nomer==0):
        nomer=15
    xc=(nomer-1)
    yc=(str_str-1)
    return xc,yc

for i in button:
    globals()[f"button{n}"]=Button(text=i,font="Arial 20",command=partial(com,i))
    x,y=cordinat(n)
    globals()[f"button{n}"].grid(column=x,row=y)
    n+=1
root.mainloop()
```

Печатать с помощью его можно, но очень не удобно.

Comment: Тут нужно при получении вашим окном фокуса возвращать фокус предыдущему окну (которое раньше было в фокусе). Как это сделать сходу я не нашел. Еще комментарий по поводу вашего кода: используйте список для кнопок вместо  `globals()[f"button{n}"]`. Лучше никогда неиспользовать `globals()` для таких целей (очень редко когда вообще на практике может действительно понадобиться `globals()`). И `global write` не нужно, т.к. вы не модифицируете переменную `write`.